# How to update value of a key present at any level in a JSON using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, json, ramda.js

Is there a way to find the value of a key, which can be present at any level under any object and update it using Ramda?

For eg.,

JSON-1

```
{
  "query": {
    "boundary": {
      "type": "polygon",
      "coordinates": "[[-85.33604,35.055749],[-85.33604,35.07499772909699],[-85.279134,35.07499772909699],[-85.279134,35.055749],[-85.33604,35.055749]]"
    }
}
```

JSON-2

```
{
  "query": {
    "nearby": {
      "radius": "30mi",
      "coordinates": "[-121.40019800,38.55378300]"
    }
  }
}
```

In both these JSON, I want to do something like:

`query.nearby.coordinates = JSON.parse(query.nearby.coordinates)`

and

`query.boundary.coordinates = JSON.parse(query.boundary.coordinates)`

with a single functionality.

Comment: Is the key always called "coordinates"?

Comment: Yes @HåkenLid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to traverse the object tree, and try to parse any string you find as JSON.

```
const parseNestedJSON = R.cond([
   [R.is(String), R.tryCatch(JSON.parse, R.nthArg(1))],
   [R.is(Object), obj => R.map(parseNestedJSON, obj)],
   [R.T, R.identity],
])
```

Note that this might do some unwanted conversion, such as turning `{foo: '1'}` into `{foo: 1}` (string to number).

It might be safer to target only nested keys called `coordinates`:

```
const parseNestedJSON = R.cond([
    [R.has('coordinates'), R.over(R.lensProp('coordinates'), JSON.parse)],
    [R.is(Object), obj => R.map(parseNestedJSON, obj)],
    [R.T, R.identity],
])
```

Edit:
If `coordinates` might not be json, you can use a `tryCatch` here as well.

```
  [R.has('coordinates'), R.over(R.lensProp('coordinates'), R.tryCatch(JSON.parse, R.nthArg(1)))]
```

Usage:

```
parseNestedJSON({"nearby": {"coordinates": "[-121.40019800,38.55378300]"}})
=> { nearby: { coordinates: [ -121.400198, 38.553783 ] } }
```

Comment: Great Answer! However, parsing needs to be done only if coordinates are of string type. So if coordinates are already an array, this is throwing error. I tried few things, but wasn't able to do it as I am new to functional programming. I'd be really grateful if you could help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to define a lens that can take care of updating the value.

The first approach will assume that there is a finite number of known paths that the coordinates can be found.

```js
// Creates a lens that accepts a list of paths and chooses the first
// matching path that exists in the target object

const somePathLens = paths => toFunctor => target => {
  const path = R.find(
    p => R.pathSatisfies(x => x != null, p, target),
    paths
  )
  return R.map(
    value => R.assocPath(path, value, target),
    toFunctor(R.path(path, target))
  )
}

// R.over can then be used with JSON.parse to parse the first
// matching path that is found.

const parseCoords = R.over(
  somePathLens([
    ['query', 'boundary', 'coordinates'],
    ['query', 'nearby', 'coordinates']
  ]),
  JSON.parse
)

console.log(parseCoords({
  "query": {
    "boundary": {
      "type": "polygon",
      "coordinates": "[[-85.33604,35.055749],[-85.33604,35.07499772909699],[-85.279134,35.07499772909699],[-85.279134,35.055749],[-85.33604,35.055749]]"
    }
  }
}))

console.log(parseCoords({
  "query": {
    "nearby": {
      "radius": "30mi",
      "coordinates": "[-121.40019800,38.55378300]"
    }
  }
}))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

This second approach can be used if the actual paths are not known and you just need to find the first value by a given key.

```js
// Recursively search for the given key in an object, returning the
// first matching path if found.

const findKeyInPath = (keyToFind, obj) => {
  const findKeyInPath_ = o =>
    R.has(keyToFind, o)
      // if found, return this key as the path
      ? [keyToFind]
      // otherwise find all keys with objects and recursively
      // call this function.
      : R.reduceRight((k, acc) => {
          // find either the subpath of this key, or the subpath
          // found in the remaining keys
          const subPath = R.when(R.isEmpty, _ => acc, findKeyInPath_(o[k]))
          // if the subpath contains a key, prepend it with the
          // current key, otherwise return the empty list
          return R.unless(R.isEmpty, R.prepend(k), subPath)
        }, [], R.filter(k => R.propIs(Object, k, o), R.keys(o)))
  return findKeyInPath_(obj)
}

// Create a lens that recursively searches for the first matching
// key within a target object.

const someKeyLens = key => toFunctor => target => {
  // find the path using our new `findKeyInPath` function
  const path = findKeyInPath(key, target)
  return R.map(
    value => R.assocPath(path, value, target),
    toFunctor(R.path(path, target))
  )
}

const parseCoords = R.over(
  someKeyLens('coordinates'),
  JSON.parse
)

console.log(parseCoords({
  "query": {
    "boundary": {
      "type": "polygon",
      "coordinates": "[[-85.33604,35.055749],[-85.33604,35.07499772909699],[-85.279134,35.07499772909699],[-85.279134,35.055749],[-85.33604,35.055749]]"
    }
  }
}))

console.log(parseCoords({
  "query": {
    "nearby": {
      "radius": "30mi",
      "coordinates": "[-121.40019800,38.55378300]"
    }
  }
}))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

It is worth mentioning that these are only valid lenses if it is guaranteed that a path will be found in the target object, otherwise the behaviour is undefined.